# Compare two CSV files for differences python

Tags: python, pandas

New to python. I have around 70 CSV files in a folder. I would like to compare those files in pair of two like *1and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4* in that format. Now my files have same name though they have a suffix *rev with a number like thin **Cars****rev1, cars_rev2, cars_rev3, cars rev4*. I have tried this code but it gives an error :

```
# your directory path here
path = r'path'

# get all files 
file_, pat = [], re.compile('.csv')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    file_ = [os.path.join(root, f) for f in files if pat.search(f)]

# you may want to filter here, this line is just an example
# filter for all csv files containing 'rev'
file_ = [f for f in file_ if 'rev' in f]

temp =[]

for i in range(len(file_)-1):
    file1="cars_rev{}.csv".format(str(i+1))
    file2="cars_rev{}.csv".format(str(i+2))

    df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)
    comparison_values = df1.fillna(0).isin(df2.fillna(0)) 
    #print (comparison_values)

    rows, cols = np.where(comparison_values==False)

    for item in zip(rows,cols):
        # do calculation
        for item in zip(rows,cols):
            df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]],df2.iloc[item[0], item[1]])
            #print(df1)

            temp.append(df1)
```

is there a possible way I can user the suffix rev1, rev2,rev3,rev4  to read those files and compare in pairs of two

Comment: why not use a simple bash script with `diff`?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom How, please help me with how I should do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [itertools.tee()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) addresses the need  "I would like to compare those files in pair of two like 1and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4 in that format."

There is recipe provided in [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Comment: Have read through, I am just stuck at implementing it in this case because I am new to python

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash solution according to the author's request:

```
$ cat compare.sh
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1;i<=7;i++));
do
    for ((j=i+1;j<=7;j++));
    do
        diff ./cars_rev$i.csv ./cars_rev$j.csv 1>/dev/null
        printf 'diff %s %s = %s\n' cars_rev$i.csv cars_rev$j.csv $?
    done
done
```

Just change the `7` to `70` or whatever else you need ...

Comment: I have written it, now am I supposed to direct my script to this bash script

Comment: either call `compare.sh` directly, or call it from python.